# The smallest disk containing all sides of an $n$-gon

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, packing-and-covering

Start with a regular $n$-gon of side 1 and consider its sides as open segments that can be moved around in the plane, allowing only translations. Two segments may not intersect.

> What is the radius of the smallest disk that can contain (cover) all segments?

For $n=3$ it is clear that the equilateral triangle with $r=\dfrac1{\sqrt{3}}$ is best possible.
But already for $n=4$, we can do better than a square, by shifting two perpendicular segments as shown on the left below and placing the two other ones at small distances parallel to them. So we can realize $r={\sqrt{\dfrac38}}+\epsilon< \dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}$.
Likewise for $n=5$, where the three black edges of the pentagon can be moved inside such that the whole fits in the blue circle with diameter $\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}2$, thus $r=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}4<\sqrt{\dfrac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10}}$ (the circumradius of the pentagon, orange circle). And there is still room for improvement, as the blue circle can be made smaller after pushing one of the grey segments diagonally upwards.
 [image]
For even $n$, the segments come in pairs of same slope, so it makes sense to ignore one of each pair. Then e.g. for $n=4$, there is no need for epsilons or $r_{inf}$, and we can state $r_{min}={\sqrt{\dfrac38}}$. Further, $n=6$ reduces to the $n=3$ case.
For $n>6$, the unit circle does the job for a star-like constellation, shifting each segment in a way that $O$ is one of its endpoints. (Well, it also does it for smaller $n$, but worse than the above constructions.)

> Is $r=1$ best possible for $n\ge7$? And what is $r_{min}$ for $n=5$?

Comment: Imagine the letters T and V typed into the same spot (and that the sides of the V make a right angle). This configuration shows that $r_{min} \leq \sqrt{1/2}$ for $n = 8$.

Comment: @WillBrian Right. I start wondering if the optimal constructions for even $n$ are very different of the ones for odd $n$.

Comment: Possibly. It's not too hard to show (generalizing the $n = 8$ picture) that you can always do better than $r = 1$ for even $n$.

Comment: For sure $r<0.99$ for any $n$.

Comment: For n=5, the small partial trapezoid pictured can include a fourth edge, and the minimal radius should reduce to a nice search.  It will be slightly larger than sin(pi/5), but not by much, and may be smaller than the 0.685 I claimed elsewhere.  Gerhard "After Five, Then Comes Seven" Paseman, 2015.11.06

Comment: After this problem is understood, a more general problem should be considered:  Take a simple closed curve ( for now, the boundary of a convex region should do) and remove n points from it.  How tightly can one pack the n pieces in a disk without rotation or overlap?  As a start take the problem above and the one where the n points removed are midpoints of the n sides of a regular polygon.  Gerhard "That Should Be Impossible Enough" Paseman, 2015.11.13.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Sure. Welcome to the new field in combinatorics which might be called ***the curve puzzle problem***, with "puzzle" in the original sense of putting pieces together. I would even start with a circle instead of an n-gon. (I love symmetries.) A shutter construction seems again to allow $r<1$ experimentally for that if $n\ge3$, but I haven't done the trig yet.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman If I got it right, for $n=4$ the shutter gives $r=\sqrt{\dfrac{35-6\sqrt{10}}{20}}\approx.895$. This is when each circle segment touches the next at angle arctan(1/3),which is best.

Comment: Indeed.  For large n and equidivision, your tractrix/fan might give the same near-optimal results.  Gerhard "Same Proof, With A Twist?" Paseman, 2015.11.14

Answer (score 11):

Start by arranging all the segments into a single unit-radius half-disk. Then cut a wedge of about $39$ degrees and slide it down along with its contents as in the figure. You did not cut or rotate any of the segments and the circumscribing circle has radius of about $0.94$.

[image]

Comment: Why 39 degrees?

Comment: I played around with the numbers by hand, but to optimize this construction you want the bottom edge of the blue wedge to be a chord of the circumcircle and the bottom-right point of the blue wedge to have a tangent parallel to its top edge. You can also improve (I think) by cutting another small wedge from the other end of the red wedge and putting it in the empty space above the red wedge.

Comment: This is a more compact version of the stacking idea I posted.  Using your visualization, I think you can find a specific value of n_0 (and a few more cuts of the red piece) such that for all n > n_0 the required radius is a value less than 0.9.  Gerhard "Or At Least Ten Elevenths" Paseman, 2015.11.03

Comment: Based on this construction, we may formulate a similar question independent of $n$ (or more precisely: fitting all $n$): ***How to cut a half unit disk into a number of wedges that can be re-arranged (by translations) to fit into the smallest possible disk?*** It looks like the optimal solution(s) of this are highly asymmetric!

Comment: @Wolfgang Sure. You may also allow point reflections (rotations by 180 degrees) of the wedges.

Comment: You can also shear the wedges.  Pushing the top of the blue wedge to the right, and fracturing and shearing the red wedge should get the radius down quite a bit, perhaps down to 6/7.  Gerhard "Fun At The Pizza Parlor" Paseman, 2015.11.03

Comment: @YoavKallus Yeah. Once the limit radius (without allowing point reflections) found, it would be interesting to look whether it decreases when we do allow those. I would not think so. BTW I'd expect that an optimal construction has infinitely many wedges with decreasing angles - but that is just a gut feeling.

Answer (score 3):

(This should be rather a comment to Yoav's answer, but a picture says more than 1000 comments.)

What about talking the two wedges and splitting the blue one into smaller wedges as shown, starting at the bottom and pushing each part rightmost against the circle? The result will be best if the blue parts have infinitesimally small angles. The blue area would then fill an area of $\pi/4$ between the circle on the right and a smooth curve obeying a certain differential equation on the left, which depends only on $r$ and the angle of the wedge (for which I have chosen 90° here). The angle and $r$ would then have to be optimized under the condition that there remains just enough space for the red wedge, probably as a whole.
I guess this is close to Gerhard's most recent idea. The missing link: finding the equation of that curve or at least some bounds...

***EDIT: Thanks to Will Brian for alluding to the tractrix. After [calculations by Robert Bryant in the tractrix thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223031/a-tricky-tractrix-question-about-vertical-tangents/223049#223049), for an angle of 90° this construction can be done with $r\approx 0.8250033$ - which is within Gerhard Paseman's estimated range.

Of course the question remains whether 90° is best.***
[image]

Comment: The curve should be something like a tractrix. For a normal tractrix, we imagine ourselves dragging something on a string while walking along a straight line; for this curve, we're walking around a circle instead.

Comment: I've managed to convince myself that for n=5, R_min is less than 0.7, through a non-tractrix construction. For a nonoptimal construction with r=0.698 nearly, take a gray edge from the pentagon and translate it inside the black three-sided trapezoid.  One sees that there is room to push things around for a smaller circumscribing circle.  Based on the tightness of this, I suspect R_min is greater than 2/3 for n=5 and for n greater than 7.  Gerhard "Glad To See Tractrix Number" Paseman, 2015.11.09

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Have you done some trig or high precision drawing to come up with 3 decimals? Or have you instructed some program to use only non-overlapping segments and circles?

Comment: All work by hand, with a cheat at the end.  I got r^2 = 1/4 + (1.5 tan 18)^2 with 18 being degrees, since the circle circumscribes the larger partial  trapezoid.  The calculator tells me r is about 0.698 .  I could have made a mistake, but the pictures suggest a value near 0.7 to me.  Gerhard "Feel Free To Correct Me" Paseman, 2015.11.09

Comment: This approach suggests a try at a good lower bound for arbitrary n.  One needs to  pack two near T's with one edge being a proper chord and all other edges being on the same side of that chord.  It may not be tight, but I am basing my 2/3 estimate on an incomplete argument using these four edges.  Gerhard "Likes To Use Suggestive Mathematics" Paseman, 2015.11.09

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Yes I'm with you now on your n=5 construction. The circumcircle of a trapezoid with bases $\phi=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}2$ and $1+\phi^3=2\phi$ and both legs equal to 1 (which happens to have angles 72° and 108°).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variant on Will Brian's idea, but inspired by the fan arrangement in the other answer.

As before, we treat only odd n, arrange them in a fan, but now we start moving the edges to the bottom.  The horizontal edge is the bottommost edge, the next edge with least positive slope goes above this segment and slightly to the right (so its midpoint is above and to the right of the midpoint of the horizontal segment), its mirror image above and slightly to the left.  As above, I won't do the algebra, but I imagine at least n/4 of the edges can be stacked this way before reaching the top half of the semicircle, leaving a depression into which the rest of the edges can sink.  I suspect for n=7 one can beat the cosine pi/7 value reached by the pinwheel construction.

Gerhard "Don't Close The Suitcase Yet!" Paseman, 2015.11.03

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can do better than r=1.  The small and even cases are handled in the post, so I focus on the case of an odd number of sides.

Instead of arranging sides in a star, arrange them in a fan or in open pages of a book, taking up less than a semicircle (semidisk?).  Move the horizontal edge down near the bottom out of the way. Split the remaining edges in half, each occupying a quarter disk.  Ease one of the quarter disks down slightly, and the other quarter disk toward the center.

As n gets large, not much movement will be available, but more than 0.  ( For large n, less than .01 this way.  Sorry, Anton.)

Gerhard "Exact Radius Will Cost More" Paseman, 2015.11.03

Comment: One can also consider a camera shutter construction, or pinwheel (extend each edge in one direction, clockwise or ccw).  I don't feel like doing that algebra though.  Gerhard "Maybe Anton Will Do It" Paseman, 2015.11.03

Comment: Ok, I'll do the geometry, and others can do the trig.  Consider translating the top horizontal edge down and to the right to be a right side radius.  Somewhere (maybe halfway) in between is where it should stop.  This will give a small and maybe optimal value. I don't know yet if it will be less than 1. Gerhard "Needs More Coffee For Trigonometry" Paseman, 2015.11.03

Comment: Ok, fine. cos($\pi/n$).  Gerhard "Double Check My Work Please" Paseman, 2015.11.03

Comment: Yes I have just found the same minimum for the camera shutter construction.

Answer (score 1):

(This should be a comment on Wolfgang's answer/comment, but there's too much to say.) Consider unit length chords approaching the center of a circle of radius $r$. The chord part would actually be longer than unit length, but we will have endpoints lie on other chords.

Suppose we start with one chord below the circle at a distance of $-y_0$, so we are dealing with chords at the bottom.  The new chord to be stacked has an endpoint on the current chord and makes an angle $\alpha$ with the current chord, and is pushed so that its other endpoint lies on the circle, so the chord intercepts the circle at abscissa $y_1 = y_0 + \sin \alpha$ .  However, we are interested in how far this chord is from the center, so we rotate the whole diagram by $\alpha$ to make the new chord horizontal.  This gives $y_2 = y_1\cos \alpha - \sqrt{r^2 - (y_1)^2}\sin \alpha$, so this second chord is at distance $-y_2 \lt -y_0$ from the circle center.

Starting with $y_0= -\sqrt{r^2 - 1/4}$, we iterate this for $\alpha=\pi/n$, giving a construction similar to the camera shutter but here the chords go only halfway around and are at different distances from the center of the circle.  For those wishing to investigate further, iterate for $n-1$ times the map
$$f_{r,n}(x) = x\cos \pi/n + \frac{\sin 2\pi/n}{2} - 
 r \sin \pi/n \sqrt{1 - \big(\frac{x + \sin \pi/n}{r}\big)^2},$$
starting with values of $r$ near $0.94$ (thanks to Yoav Kallus).  I suspect for $n=5$ we can get $r_{min}$ below $0.8$.

Gerhard "Round And Round We Go" Paseman, 2015.11.05

Comment: On further consideration, it looks like r could be chosen not much larger than r satisfying r_0 + sqrt((r_0)^2 - 1/4) greater than (sin a)(1 + cos a + cos 2a + ... + cos (n-2)a) for a= pi/n.  (Actually, it needs to be greater by  a small amount depending on n, but this shows a lower bound for r for this construction.)  Gerhard "Definitely Needs Someone Else Checking" Paseman, 2015.11.05

Comment: Using this method, I believe $r_{min} \lt 0.78$ for $n=5$.  Verfication would be nice.  Also, contrasting this with the other suggested method (interleaving book pages instead of doing a partial camera shutter) would be nice, in which case vary $\alpha$ from $\pi/n$ to $(n-2)\pi/n$ in steps of $\pi/n$, although stopping early is allowed.  It might help to note that the case $n=4$ can't be beat, and that all other $n$ need stricty greater $r$. Gerhard "More Than I Will Do" Paseman, 2015.11.05

Comment: Also, once $r_{min}$ has been established for a few small odd integers $n$ (say $5,7,9$), then that can be used to estimate $r_{min}$ for larger $n$ as they will have edges close to those for the small integers, close enough that likely one can show their minimum radii are strictly greater.  Gerhard "Should Have Seen This Already" Paseman, 2015.11.05

Comment: I think $r_{min}$ for $n=5$ is half of the long side of a triangle with sides $1,\phi=0.618..$ and included angle $4\pi/5$, which is a little more than $0.685$.  For larger $n$ I conjecture $r_{min}$ is in $[0.7,0.85]$.  Gerhard "Can't Be Too Far Wrong" Paseman, 2015.11.05.